# NSButton wrap title dynamically

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, interface-builder

**What I want to accomplish:**
I need a checkbox with a title text that dynamically wraps and breaks on multiple lines depending on a dynamic width established by the parent view. I need a solution that I can use in IB and that will display there as it's shown at runtime. I'm using XCode 13.1, working in a XIB-File targetting MacOS.

**What I'm doing:**
I create an NSButton in IB. In the attributes inspector I set its style to `Check`, under "Control" I choose `Word Wrap` for "Line Break" and finally I set a very long text as the title such as `Asd Asd Asd lit tle words and many of them asd asd lit tle ones`.

**What's happening:**
When setting up the button as described above (*case 1)* and shrinking its width, it will be displayed - in IB and at runtime - like this:

[image: Title not wrapping correctly]

When manually adding a line break to the title as suggested in [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671136/wrap-nsbutton-title) by pressing `Option` `+` `Enter` (*case 2*, here after "them") the title starts wrapping correctly and all the other necessary breaks are generated:

[image: Title wrapping correctly]

However this solution is not applicable for my case since it only works for a static width, but my checkboxes need to adjust their width dynamically as described above.

Without that additional manual line break it's most interesting that apparently the checkbox is already reacting and changing its position according to the new wrapped height of the title while the title text itself is just clipped by the bounds of the control instead of being displayed in a wrapped fashion.

**What I'd expect:**
I'd expect the title to wrap in case 1. Since it doesn't: Is this a bug or a feature? How can I make case 1 work and get the title to wrap dynamically depending on its length and the width of the button? Do I just need to set another attribute in the inspector I missed so far? Or is there only a programmatic solution?

*To answer the question why I don't use an appropriately short label: Don't ask me, I'm just a developer following specs & reqs and unfortunately I don't have a saying on what would be a good length of text here.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wrap NSButton title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671136/wrap-nsbutton-title)

Comment: I've found this thread; unfortunately didn't help. The marked answers (and others with it) suggest using a shorter text, which is not applicable, or subclass NSButtonCell, but without giving directions how. Another answer suggests adding a newline character (which I did), but this only works for static, not dynamic cases. Subclassing an NSControl is also not useful for me, since I'll be using them aside a great number of single-line checkboxes that are all supposed to work the same way. Additionally I'll need full IB support for Bindings.

Comment: AppKit doesn't support multi-line checkboxes. How about a short title and an explanation like the "Close windows when quitting an app" setting in System Prefs?

Comment: Hey @Willeke, thanks for your suggestion! Unfortunately any kind of GUI improvements by changing specs, effectively defining the problem away is not possible. I'm required to have this look like any other singleline checkbox. Nevertheless thanks to your statement that AppKit just doesn't allow for this I've stopped tweaking the button to do the impossible but looked for a suitable workaround. Take a look below for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The credits for this answer goes to [@Willeke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4244136/willeke)'s comment: "AppKit doesn't support multiline checkboxes." The interesting behaviour of the checkbox in case 1 suggesting otherwise seems to be just a glitch or bug.

**What I ended up with:** I opted for a workaround. I'm placing a checkbox-button (with Image Position "Image only" in IB) right beside a multiline-label, putting both in a custom view, adding the necessary constraints. With a few positioning adjustments I know have a solution that looks exactly like a singleline checkbox, that I can copy-paste in IB and that is solved by Autolayout - in IB and at runtime - without any additional code.

Comment: Don't forget to put a click gesture recognizer on your view so that clicking the label toggles the checkbox. Unfortunately it won't have the "dimming" behavior during mouse down that a real checkbox has but this at least gets you the nice UX of having the whole label clickable just like a real checkbox.